# Passing additional arguments to rectangleselector method

Tags: python, matplotlib, lambda, functools

I am using the rectangleselector in matplotlib and trying to pass to it additional arguments. Here is a basic code example of my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector

word = "watermelon"

x = np.arange(0,100,1)
y = x**3

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y,'r--')

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease, additional_argument):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print(x1, y1)
    print(additional_argument)

rs = RectangleSelector(ax, lambda event, word: line_select_callback,
                    drawtype='box', useblit=False, button=[1],
                    minspanx=5, minspany=5, spancoords='pixels',
                    interactive=True)

plt.show()
```

If you remove the additional_argument from the method and change `lambda event, word: line_select_callback` to simply `line_selec_callback` then the code runs perfectly well. But for the requirements of a bigger project the ability to pass additional arguments is required.

I have tried working with lambda functions and functools.partial but I can't seem to get either to work in this case. I am still learning python so apologies if this question is a basic one. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What is the criterion by which you want to pass the argument. As it stands you have one fixed argument `word` and this can be passed to the function, e.g. using `lambda eclick, erelease: line_select_callback(eclick, erelease, word)`. However this has the same effect than just using `line_selec_callback` as callback and using the variable `word` inside the function. So you need to tell us how you would like the workflow to be when having multiple possible arguments. How would you determine which one is the one to be used`?

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this worked for me great. It seems I was using lambda functions incorrectly and need to look over them more. As a wider context my larger code project was trying to pass Tkinter Entry widgets to the RectangeSelector. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hii @ImportanceOfBeingErnest        I have two arguments/parameters inside the line_select_callback. Eg line_select_callback(paramter_1, parameter_2). When I directly call using line_select_callback(paramter_1, parameter_2) syntax, I am getting error like this. TypeError: line_select_callback() missing 2 required positional arguments: "parameter_1" and "parameter_2" . Advance thankyou